# Newtonsoft keeps throwing Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException. Why?

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, json.net

I'm working with the following json:

```
[
  {
    "file": {
      "type": "external",
      "size": 0,
      "sizeUnit": "",
      "url": "resources/asyncworldedit.327/download?version=381454",
      "externalUrl": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/releases/tag/v3.8.2"
    },
    "likes": 64,
    "testedVersions": [
      "1.7",
      "1.8",
      "1.9",
      "1.10",
      "1.11",
      "1.12",
      "1.13",
      "1.14",
      "1.15",
      "1.16"
    ],
    "links": {
      "b2xkIHZlcnNpb24gMy41LjQgYW5kIFdFIDYuMS43LjM=": "https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/asyncworldedit-premium.9661/history",
      "aGVyZQ==": "http://www.spigotmc.org/threads/asyncworldedit-what-performance-you-may-expect.56947/",
      "V29ybGRFZGl0IEZvcmdl": "http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/225608-worldedit",
      "QW1hemluZ1RlcnJhaW5HZW5lcmF0b3I=": "https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/amazingterraingenerator-generate-custom-terrain-like-a-terraformer.26844/",
      "Qm91bnRpZnVsQVBJ": "http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/bountifulapi.1394/",
      "R2l0aHVi": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit-API",
      "cHJlbWl1bQ==": "https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/asyncworldedit-premium.9661/",
      "discussion": "threads/asyncworldedit.11441/",
      "V29ybGRFZGl0": "http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/worldedit/",
      "QWN0aW9uTWVzc2FnZXI=": "http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/actionmessager.4592/",
      "QmFyQVBJ": "http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/bar-api/",
      "UGx1Z2luIEFQSQ==": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit-Premium/wiki/API",
      "QWN0aW9uQmFyQVBJ": "http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/actionbarapi.1315/",
      "c3BpZ290bWMub3Jn": "http://www.spigotmc.org/threads/asyncworldedit-what-performance-you-may-expect.56947/",
      "UGxvdE1l": "http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/plotme/",
      "UHJlbWl1bSBkb3dubG9hZCBwYWdl": "https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/asyncworldedit-premium.9661/",
      "additionalInformation": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/wiki",
      "R2l0SHVi": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/wiki",
      "QXN5bmNXb3JsZEVkaXQgLSBCb3NzIEJhcg==": "https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/asyncworldedit-boss-bar.76600/",
      "Um9hZG1hcA==": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit-Premium/wiki/Roadmap",
      "alternativeSupport": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/issues",
      "UGVybWlzc2lvbnMgcGFnZQ==": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/wiki/Permissions",
      "R2l0aHViIGZvcms=": "https://github.com/Aurelien30000/ActionBarAPI",
      "V29ybGRFZGl0IDcuMS4w": "https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldedit?gameCategorySlug=bukkit-plugins&projectID=31043",
      "VGl0bGVNYW5hZ2Vy": "http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/titlemanager.1049/",
      "bGluaw==": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/wiki/License",
      "Q29tbWFuZHMgcGFnZQ==": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/wiki/Commands",
      "V2VsY29tZVRpdGxl": "http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/spigot-1-8-welcometitle.1063/",
      "V29ybGRFZGl0IDYuMS4yIChjaGVjayByZWxlYXNlIG5vdGVzIGZvciBleGFjdCB2ZXJzaW9uKQ==": "https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldedit?gameCategorySlug=bukkit-plugins&projectID=31043",
      "Q29uZmlndXJhdGlvbiBwYWdl": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/wiki/Configuration",
      "QXN5bmNXb3JsZEVkaXQgUHJlbWl1bQ==": "https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/asyncworldedit-premium.9661/",
      "QmxvY2tzSHVi": "https://github.com/SBPrime/BlocksHub/wiki",
      "UmVhZA==": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/wiki/Lag/"
    },
    "name": "AsyncWorldEdit",
    "tag": "Async WorldEdit - Edit millions of blocks without lag!",
    "version": {
      "id": 381454,
      "uuid": "00000eb3-0a2d-acde-0000-947ebad08eb5"
    },
    "author": {
      "id": 1621
    },
    "category": {
      "id": 15
    },
    "rating": {
      "count": 201,
      "average": 4.25131
    },
    "icon": {
      "url": "data/resource_icons/0/327.jpg?1391290736",
      "data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx4BBQUFBwYHDggIDh4UERQeHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHv/CABEIAGAAYAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAdAAAABwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwQFBgcIAQkC/9oACAEBAAAAAMcEgAAAA4mZtK5a5RJ/e4lJK6VzF9YW59QOC1geqyUWUSCINMj1ib6q9RahL2wwOVuzq3FVYlN3HaHnvDxK/Qiu8LkG7iVxW8PPcrVN91hHsT7cvzETRuthTZOuCnLsNq/YmY2HXdSk13cMInuf8t6c06mi2B/jetwDIWWwNOXTglAFm9Kjy2DiR3gA7wHf/8QAGgEAAwADAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYHAQMFBP/aAAgBAhAAAAAAAADEvpWZnUYd20h2XO1sVvR3pvUauivAjPf/xAAZAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAUDAQL/2gAIAQMQAAAAAAaEC/P1uVcvbl5V8c7c7OrkWR//xAAoEAACAgIBBAEEAwEBAAAAAAADBAIFAQYHABETFBIQFRckISMwFiX/2gAIAQEAAQwBMQhizKWciE/yCQgSwKGchk6utfZr810Ry9mRKiwGsRmQY5CTXboYCHmhPA6fXzMWKQbHyJrS1nEEq1ohGBxxVPEXy0FacgE1ttWvsCWAirtVmpYPitg0YoDt1M8TCNcLkSP6oWFplBPBSSZDJdiYJ5jmVUcC1gFhkEjjBsvzrsLWITHItsESuMW5IJ4gjsQQIgAVUxSbFbqWbPurpFWbs9xaehaQksOGI7EPCg8epLDP/VChb2lkJGeJrbTWKsrkBVN4ghc1yoDrZSbKHO2rRZwwGuLjLpBFbKQEJjHUpEsrRWvDMcCT452n2phWUCzEPHuzlUMfCoMSxx1t+Zxhirj3xx/tuYfPFV/FzWt1FiWvehEbFRpN5bUYbZCICjjx/tkg+aNZjMPxztOQjmNVcsvx7t3x+X2rvj8d7d5Ph9rj0ccwmmEnbE0GjIuhcXzjBvyTtGMR+B14TW33a5k8K5xzJZbTv2ulCvYfqylyHtMgzFJwOYXts7d2U7GwnGZ6Xdtgp68CCTAYrz5G2fIxwGwAOKjZ95vZmRrIwP0bkDcFiSWK1ERM8jbVmXeTYM9OMFbbM0eXyL0EZDFiIUJEJxjoo6IUbOzhGdns9EhsNXNB8ffG2a8/rlpJJ2PfH01ahf2K0gijDrVNfQ1yriijDrkzRhbACVhXxiO0OIq55gOOQy9BGQxYiFCUycZaKOiFGzs4RnZ8rbd9grfQSJ/6XDe4e4GOv2Re7Gz0SGw1c0Hx98bZrz+uWkknYd8atQv7FaQRRh1a29PxpXp1NcvFlureWsq8LyZcEBv+8LawwqrAWGWd61NHcKod9RyH7jASrnmA45DLxbpAadUVu/iJbCXf45+PbvvusmR2VNu9t4Nda9rA7Xb5J0lrhfpOJ4qii0SBD7PRIbDVzQfH3xrOvp65T+jWwj5Ng1N0+1OxtrTzNcRVdvX0czwdAZK818Qtofhs1tArXDtbZI0uDydEat5P0gN6tOzRxEVlxZv3p+KkuzfrY/nHfHXOM1xu69NqPyDxCVE29tSr4YgHrkTc1tZT8Iviay453VfZVPXYzENnyKn5NxIY1U02PjgJAaWgIoSBlsA6qG5PmuaJiwHx+KYNPQGQMw55T37z+Wjozf09cWb96eRUl2b9a9oKe9wH7onFrFJrFFStSaq6+CxuRNzW1lPwh+JrKwcZfcK44aRjpNMJNjbUNIJ+Od0X2VT12PgGz+nKe/efy0dGb+r68Wb96eRUl2b9bkLdFdaS8QMwPY2DjL7hXHDSMf6JNMJNjbUNIJ+Ot1W2RT12cwDZ8p795/LR0Zv6voYZAlmIsJDJ/kEZDFgIUJEJ/8QAORAAAgECBAQEAwUHBQEAAAAAAQIDABEEEiExMkFRYRMiYnEQI1IzQnKRsQUkMDRDodEUFSCB8PH/2gAIAQEADT8Bc5mZjck/w0OZWU2IPwxyaBBqswbK0X4gbfnUeUs6yqwGYkDY9QfyqMOWOYfc4+etudYuYQCewbI7C6hhfTcb8taxGKlw+KzRj938Pc766Zjy4TVs4NxmyZsua29r6X2vWGEZSHQ5s0mQ3rGYjEwMqhXyGJFbkd/MRY7U6NIy4iMR5UH3r3tbffpTTYWGOVyqpnmiz5WN9+nsaRrHKwI/MVG2bww1s1tuR0qPHLi4ZopBEyfWNF3bTXqopcJ4E8Ulg+LkuWR8igAkMEufT3qODFxM/jDzGdct9uX96lYSYhvHzLnt9wWFrnXW9Y9Y7W/pOL53H4s8l/x0v7PP7PZw/kaMnitbisbf3rGYiLERq8oIQpIHsdNRp2qHGYjFZWxQP20aoV4OWWsThmw8pfEjOq51dcnlsLMt+96XFYHEANOD/LJktw/evTMSqu2Yj/uwrEyrErSGygk21pXyCVZ1VSb2+8QdwdxUSo5iOITOVYFr722W9jrTEj+Zi3By/V1rwxJ9vHsQT9W9lOlRWzqrhraX3GlTTtCIzLlYWUsWN9MvlPOrBgRiI9QRcW82ulM7IUXEpdMovcm9rW6GsobSePnf1b+U/lV7X/1Edtr/AFdKRirWN9RUDiRCVuLjsaEhkzCEanygabWGUbCplWKy4Zcz2UoOWps1qu0seeFDmzPn3/ET7Xp4vCYHDpqLEdN7MacKpKqFFgLDQdhUDZ41aBWsbnXUeo1HCkQyxA3y5rHW+vmNMjl0jw6KFDLlPYaVFaNlbDqCpXN238xoOHAOGTSwAFtO1TOZHNrXJNz8HOVVUXJPSnHlXcQDoPV3o6xyDijbqKOsUo4ZF6j47ySHhjXqa3llPFI3U0g9hOOh79D/AOCNldGFiD8HOVVUXJNOPKu4gHQervWKXykf0k+r36VGP3WRjxr9PuP09qOscg4o26it4pQPLIvUVvJIeGNepqVg+JvxFObHueQqZcyMKkYNKl+CLmfc8qaPMjDQYheh6N/8PZGyujCxBqZM0Y3EKnp6u9cr1+0nkMjhfDCZQLDUnTUCsNAMSk4+ZZgwHL3oKBI6LYMetuVHWOQcUbdRVrvK+8j9WpkSdpI49PMWFtdrZaxOdoYXBvHIGK39jbWnCTeKHEYObNpr0sKxV3ii1zRNe2/Q2qJbnkJgOR79D/4cOHxDH7L0t6e/L22oNPnFr/RX+2kWC218RPhKvyouS+pu361EvzI+Ug+pf8UcJEEaPDNIL3e+w9qHieR1ykfMbkafDQCB1wTTAEZ82w7ilVvI65SvnPKuHE4hTx+le3fn8OHD4hj9l6W9Pfl7bQ38O7EWva+x7CnTIzB2N1uDbU9hUq/Ki5L6m7frUrZndtzUTZkdTqDUS/Mj5SD6l/x8eHE4lDx+le3U/wDDhw+IY/Z+lvT35e20q/Kjvoo+pu361K2Z3bc/GJsyOp1BqJfmJsJB9S/4rhxOJQ8fpXt3+KHKysLEH+G5yqqi5Jr/xAAkEAEBAAICAQQCAwEAAAAAAAABEQAhMUFREGFxgZGxIKHhMP/aAAgBAQABPxBW4ViTVV5V/wCZtQrAmiJwj6aRCrqhZ3ET2TCAiGUjqUQa7XjLoAS6cgK9lYCuhxzxsRRAmxJDUUMKASApD438R9XN6qVsIO/LT0W5E5UuIEKiPBN6eJZv4n05OUoQUceativqhaFhsR9xhbc50C4CmRRNiytIkyJPCI4X47FbYKhsFJsprnAbP8yaBRgPcRG5MtZW7JegFANU1VhLjZbUrSVZWuzGSP7SIUWNFSGAgNdlUHrrjp/NPGQI5HQ8tbXKUOkepM8j5dmNaD3g3gSZQB6QR2vfOlDs0IruSkI7TXOEZ/e7w0HBN6TvCvnREtiAX6MjByf0FRhXw4/eHD0gC0AgInGyzjJ0DgEEZIQiDuM4l+ApC6HIPMZZgGixoQPRooPI1rZiVzAOkDa8E1dcO8AXwhzQkwN2pxj+nYdpQVQXXhxttO+bYDVIpIjGC0kQVSjIBs1U5OUwTlLCu1u9KG4LgJCBIxFHZyMw7+aiYSgiU4SOCdJrCwBSgDAO7VXClsf4h1VLy48YyA4Q9KYEZoXo8YMVLFG9vIBe8kZuSGQE0GMKHTWrSN7LZPGUnEWAhX3nIcQIYjv5GqmhRQ3V3two6wWhsdKVvb7YLs1gMV0ACdju3eAEFsBZIaNro9BPhWJMAG1XrKGEpEj4FHPTg7XjYITS0/nycJpzY3R7tfk8nI/S+la6wd3tv+jldGUMLCTW236OAzYH2aENP0T9DqOHEaRDMRHhH0E+lYkwANqvWXMJSJHwKOenB2pxQkRttPtWz3V62jqu0kyrXkNnkfbeQQJpafz5OE05TM19ta9zycj9LWusHd7b/o5XRjFk5wzHnGw4jb1sN3+4HpOkaJ0iYI7Pw2/ZQ+Feq7MeRE14yQXhPA4QRpEMxEeEcLPzgNoeSHfTg7X2wvgvV9s0gzis4gNIdBMrDVQoEKIiX6xOywDTYSwu5WZvwIE1NP58nCaco00zItIbl4Dg4w17ECggi0EB4h1g2RB4oo10R7J3QixuWIDqCA0EMNms+I0nBCk8xO6l/wD0u+kh/Q6jhGsufCgj+HwOCASiUR5wiS9JJOveVGhQ+Zr8eidXy7RdauPA5R4qArqAwH9Xnp8ZKAyrElQHeC3vTxqAgJpM0SpFGAoD+nNxzmiVBWzSZ79XxYsfVHsNW4jMufAgj+HwOCLeLG6yVvZ4x9IWwiIQ5T6xPTijRdauPA5R4qJx8jUf0dAaAAwtEIoXf+d4MekDQP6vPT49FAroz34/iBc+gc8GrfVGZc+BRH8PgcN1PjpXEvwOV7VE48QqP6OgNBo9S0Qghd/53hmtVYHPteenxnux/EC59Uc8GtvorcKwJiI8I+qq1V/iKNFH1FuFYkwAOVc//8QALxEAAQIEBgAEBQUBAAAAAAAAAQIRAwQFIQAGEjFBUQcTImFCUmJxgTCRoaLB4v/aAAgBAgEBPwD9QkAOcT/iZKy9SECEjXBFlKG79p7A/tw1nlpmFNQkxoKgpKg4I2IxMTEKWhKjRlBKUhyTsBiS8TZWPUzAio0wDZKuX7UOAf3Ty92BBDjGeM7mcUqnyCmhiylfN2B9PfzfbeVy1RlZWUpUQEEajFY2ULWs+kH0s1w53Zso5vi0GP5EU6oBNwOPqT/os46OJaqwM5VUy0VTS8MEhFwYhHxKbYB3Afrl2oGU6dHr0aTixQtEN2Td1cMbBtHN7lms+KDmmHQqgujzMXXBSpkL5TdtKvYGx6Nx6TbPORvN1VCnp9W60DntSR32OdxdwZfNknCy2qlFCvMKVB7abq1dv/GMk5JVU1CdnQ0EbD5/+ezzsLOcVehxMpzqqvT4euEQQUuRodr2c6bfjY2Y4lq8uBUI07ovE1WCiltRBsRfj84ylk8x5g1ipIZSiVJQeHLup+egfubsBif8P6bOVITpsndSBso9+z/EBv7OXQhKEhKQwGwwpKVpKVBwcSXh/TJSpmeF07pQdknv3A+EHb3YNj//xAApEQABBAECBAUFAAAAAAAAAAABAAIDBBESMRATISJBUYGhsRQwMmGR/9oACAEDAQE/APusoOdHk7pzS04Ka0uOAn0HCPI34VKmnvfunTy/Ubeis1hMMjdGJ1aPUPyPj5Kay8QhwGCVNXMzBK0YPiFUt47H/wBRgeZdfTGc/tW7fL7Gb/Cgn54DHnr8oxZYG+Ss2sN5TD68GXZGx6PdE5WyfdkdHo9+H//Z",
      "info": "",
      "hash": ""
    },
    "releaseDate": 1391290680,
    "updateDate": 1612373951,
    "downloads": 261825,
    "premium": false,
    "sourceCodeLink": "https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/",
    "donationLink": "https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/asyncworldedit-premium.9661/",
    "existenceStatus": 1,
    "id": 327
  }
]
```

This is from Spiget API, and here is the link to exactly what the API query is: "[https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/worldedit](https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/)"
I manually wrote out this whole class structure:

```
    public class file
    {
        public string type { get; set; } 
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string sizeUnit { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string? externalUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class version
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string uuid { get; set; }
    }

    public class author
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class category
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class rating
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public double average { get; set; }
    }

    public class icon
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
        public string hash { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public file file { get; set; }
        public int likes { get; set; }
        public List<string> testedVersions { get; set; }
        public List<string> links { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public version version { get; set; }
        public author author { get; set; }
        public category category { get; set; }
        public rating rating { get; set; }
        public icon icon { get; set; }
        public int releaseDate { get; set; }
        public int updateDate { get; set; }
        public int downloads { get; set; }
        public bool premium { get; set; }
        public string sourceCodeLink { get; set; }
        public string donationLink { get; set; }
        public int existenceStatus { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

Key information: `externalUrl` is sometimes there and sometimes not, something I also have to deal with.
And then to finish things off, I used the following code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
dynamic JSONData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(wc.DownloadString("https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/worldedit?field=name&size=1"));
Console.WriteLine(JSONData.testedVersions);
```

Basically I'm working with Spiget and I'm trying to deserialize the json data that the API gives to me. However, I keep getting the same error. I've tried using autogenerated class structures, borrowed code, etc, and nothing is working. I even resorted to writing out the class structure I referenced earlier which took forever, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Double check your types. `file.size` should be an int but you made it a string in your class.

Comment: @Turksarama Thanks I appreciate it! I just went through, and I'll update the code shortly, but that isn't the issue. The error is still appearing

Comment: `links` is a dictionary in the JSON but a `List<string>` in your class.

Comment: You're deserializing a single `Root`, but the json is a collection of `Root`; try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IReadOnlyCollection<Root>>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The two problems with your code were:

1. You were using List for links instead of using Dictionary<string, string>
2. Also response from API was in Array form and you were trying to convert it to single object instead of converting it into List or ObservableCollection.

I made some changes in your code. Here's code:

```
public class File
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string sizeUnit { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string externalUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Version
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string uuid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rating
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public double average { get; set; }
    }

    public class Icon
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
        public string hash { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public File file { get; set; }
        public int likes { get; set; }
        public List<string> testedVersions { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> links { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public Version version { get; set; }
        public Author author { get; set; }
        public Category category { get; set; }
        public Rating rating { get; set; }
        public Icon icon { get; set; }
        public int releaseDate { get; set; }
        public int updateDate { get; set; }
        public int downloads { get; set; }
        public bool premium { get; set; }
        public string sourceCodeLink { get; set; }
        public string donationLink { get; set; }
        public int existenceStatus { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

////////////////////

```
private async void SaveAsJson()
    {
        string url = "https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/worldedit?field=name&size=1";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            string stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(stringResponse);
            ObservableCollection<Root> myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Root>>(stringResponse);
            // Do what u want to do
            MessageBox.Show(myObj.First().likes.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveAsJson();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows. The classes need to be defined as such:

```
public class File
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string sizeUnit { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string externalUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Version
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string uuid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rating
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public double average { get; set; }
    }

    public class Icon
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
        public string hash { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public File file { get; set; }
        public int likes { get; set; }
        public List<string> testedVersions { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> links { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public Version version { get; set; }
        public Author author { get; set; }
        public Category category { get; set; }
        public Rating rating { get; set; }
        public Icon icon { get; set; }
        public int releaseDate { get; set; }
        public int updateDate { get; set; }
        public int downloads { get; set; }
        public bool premium { get; set; }
        public string sourceCodeLink { get; set; }
        public string donationLink { get; set; }
        public int existenceStatus { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

And the function that uses the API needs to be written like this:

```
public static void SaveAsJson()
{
    string url = "https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/worldedit?field=name&size=1";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        ObservableCollection<Root> myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Root>>(wc.DownloadString("https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/worldedit?field=name&size=1"));
        Console.WriteLine(myObj.First().name.ToString());
    }
}
```